# EF6 and multiple configurations (SQL Server and SQL Server Compact)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, configuration, entity-framework-6

**Update:** Problem solved, see end of this question.

**The problem**:

We are trying to use Entity Framework 6 and code-based configuration in a scenario were we have use both a SQL Server and SQL Server CE in the same `AppDomain`.

This quite simple scenario seems not to be supported "by design". From the EF team:

> Note: We do not support having multiple configuration classes used in
>   the same AppDomain. If you use this attribute to set different
>   configuration classes for two contexts an exception will be thrown.

More information here: [Code-based Configuration (Codeplex)](http://entityframework.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Code-based%20Configuration)

**The question**:

How do we move forward from here? Any help would be greatly appreciated! Is there a more flexible way to connect a configuration to a context instead of an `AppDomain`?

(Our context classes are located in different assemblies. We have tried the `DbConfigurationType` attribute but the problem is EF itself)

Configuration files:

Configuration for normal SQL server

```
public class EfConfiguration : DbConfiguration
{
    public EfConfiguration()
    {
        SetProviderServices(
            SqlProviderServices.ProviderInvariantName, 
            SqlProviderServices.Instance);

        SetDefaultConnectionFactory(new SqlConnectionFactory());
    }
}
```

Configuration for SQL Server Compact Edition

```
public class EfCeConfiguration : DbConfiguration
{
    public EfCeConfiguration()
    {
        SetProviderServices(
            SqlCeProviderServices.ProviderInvariantName,
            SqlCeProviderServices.Instance);

        SetDefaultConnectionFactory(
            new SqlCeConnectionFactory(SqlCeProviderServices.ProviderInvariantName));
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

The error which we get is:

> System.TypeInitializationException : The type initializer for
>   'MyProject.Repositories.Base.DataContext'
>   threw an exception.   ----> System.InvalidOperationException : An
>   instance of 'EfCeConfiguration' was set but this type was not
>   discovered in the same assembly as the 'DataContext' context. Either
>   put the DbConfiguration type in the same assembly as the DbContext
>   type, use DbConfigurationTypeAttribute on the DbContext type to
>   specify the DbConfiguration type, or set the DbConfiguration type in
>   the config file. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=260883 for
>   more information.

**UPDATE 2, the solution**
As described above, we can only have one configuration. This is a problem since Sql and SqlCe uses different providers. If we use "SetDefaultConnectionFactory" to fit one type of database, the other will fail.

Instead, supply the connection into the context as described in the post marked as answer below. Once you always initialize the context with a connection as opposed to a connectionstring you are good to go. You can remove the SetDefaultConnectionFactory call from the configuration. We're using only the code below for configuring the SqlCe Context and no configuration for the Sql Context.

```
  public class CommonEfConfiguration : DbConfiguration
    {
        public CommonEfConfiguration()
        {
            // EF does not know if the ce provider by default,
            // therefore it is required to be informed about it.
            // The connection factories are not necessary since the connection
            // is always created in the UnitOfWork classes
            SetProviderServices(SqlCeProviderServices.ProviderInvariantName, SqlCeProviderServices.Instance);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused -- I have two databases in two separate C# projects (assemblies) each with their own configuration and have never had any issues whatsoever.

Comment: Kirk: Are you using EF6 and do you execute them in the same App-Domain? We use nunit and are performing an integration test across two systems but running them as one. Worked fine in EF5 where one didn't have to specify the provider in configuraton.

Comment: Yes, and yes.  What actual error are you experiencing?

Comment: @kirk  Discovery of the DBConfiguration if it is used is the issue. Perhaps your scenario has all pieces in the correct assembly for auto discovery. If DBConfig classes to be used are in the same assembly :-( gets nasty

Comment: @kirk: Gives me hope that you have solved this! :) I've posted the error in an update in the question.

Comment: @Henrik, the difference is that my configuration is contained in the same assembly as my data context.  Is there a reason you cannot do that?

Comment: @Kirk, Problem solved! The issue was that we were creating DbContext with connectionstrings which doesn't pairs well with a singleton connectionFactory when you want connections to Sql and SqlCe. Instead we now create the DbContext sending in specific connections. Now the configuration of the factories can be removed.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem, but between mssql and mysql.
I try to apply your solution, but MySqlEFConfiguration seems different

Comment: @Baptiste did you get it working in some way I am running into exactly the same issue with mssql & mysql together?

Comment: @Hitendra It was a long time ago, but i remember that I had to go back in EF5

Answer (score 13, accepted):

EDIT: based On Error details:
Did you already try tell EF where the config class is found?

```
[DbConfigurationType("MyNamespace.MyDbConfiguration, MyAssemblyFullyQualifiedName")]
public class MyContextContext : DbContext
{
}
```

If that cant be made work, then see alternative

Use the Context with constructor DbConnection

```
public class MYDbContext : DbContext {
     // MIgration parameterless constructor is managed in  MyMigrationsContextFactory 

    public MyDbContext(string connectionName) : base(connectionName) { } // no this

    public MYDbContext(DbConnection dbConnection, bool contextOwnsConnection)  // THIS ONE
        : base(dbConnection, contextOwnsConnection) {  }
```

you then need a "DBConnection" connection for each provider.
For SQL server

```
      public DbConnection GetSqlConn4DbName(string dataSource, string dbName) {
        var sqlConnStringBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
        sqlConnStringBuilder.DataSource = String.IsNullOrEmpty(dataSource) ? DefaultDataSource : dataSource;
        sqlConnStringBuilder.IntegratedSecurity = true;
        sqlConnStringBuilder.MultipleActiveResultSets = true;

        var sqlConnFact = new SqlConnectionFactory(sqlConnStringBuilder.ConnectionString);
        var sqlConn = sqlConnFact.CreateConnection(dbName);
        return sqlConn;
    }
```

repeat for SqlCe factory, it can also generate a DBConnection
            [SqlCe connection factor create connection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.infrastructure.sqlceconnectionfactory.createconnection%28v=vs.113%29.aspx)

Comment: Yes I did try to specify it for both configuration files. That's the message I got.

Comment: Thanks man! We already had you concept for the CE-connection but for the regular connections we used the connection string. When we instead supplied a connection to the context the configuration was not necessary anymore! (Except for the provider definition)

Comment: You could mention that MyAssembly has to be a fully qualified name.

Comment: @phil soady do you know about oracle provide?

Comment: I have never used Oracles EF provider.  Hit their website to find out more. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/downloads/odpnet-ef-nuget-121022-2585735.txt

Comment: Useful link for future viewers. Explains how to configure the sections. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj680699

Answer (score 2):

what i did:

```
public partial class MyDataBaseContext : DbContext
{
    public MyDataBaseContext (string ConnectionString)
        : base(ConnectionString)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: with something like `var ConnectionString = @"Data Source="C:\temp\mydatabase.sdf"` this works fine.

Comment: From my MVC HomeController class, I did this:    public static readonly string conStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SudentConext"].ToString();

    MyDataBaseContext db = new MyDataBaseContext(conStr);

Answer (score -1):

I found the solution in [a post on a Microsoft forum post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/20c77828-3aa2-4519-822f-b563181a021d/entity-framework-configuration-doesnt-work?forum=adodotnetentityframework&prof=required).

Basically, I had two projects, each one with its own context. Entity Framework was loading just (the first) one of the DbConfiguration classes and trying to use this same configuration for both projects. That's the reason for the error message saying something like

> "An instance of 'EfCeConfiguration' was set but this type was not discovered in the same assembly as the 'DataContext' context".

So, as someone suggested in [that Microsoft forum post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/20c77828-3aa2-4519-822f-b563181a021d/entity-framework-configuration-doesnt-work?forum=adodotnetentityframework&prof=required), I removed all `[DbConfigurationType(typeof(DbConfigurationClass))]` anotations from the classes which inherit from DbContext in both projects, and the error didn't happen anymore.

Comment: But did it run after that?  I mean, the DbConfiguration subclass you use is kind of important to it functioning correctly at runtime. It configures a lot of database-engine-specific things (e.g. completely different settings for MySQL vs MSSQL) like the dependency resolver (eg. MySqlDependencyResolver), provider factory (e.g. MySqlClientFactory), provider services (e.g. MySqlProviderServices), connection factory (e.g. MySqlConnectionFactory), migration generator, provider factory resolver, manifest token resolver, and history context.  You can't just not specify all that and have it work.

Comment: I dunno, bro. I don't remember the details of the project I was working at when I answered it, but I'm positive it solved the issue at hand at that time. Now, to check the things you are pointing out, I think you'll be better able to test it because I don't have the environment with this problem happening anymore.