# How to choose DbConfigurationType programmatically?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I have a `DbContext`:

```
[DbConfigurationType(typeof(MySqlEFConfiguration))]
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<MyClass> MyClasses { get; set; }
}
```

Now, what if I want to be able to use another `DbConfigurationType`, according to AppSettings value?

So that, I change AppSettings value from `MySQL` to `MSSQL` and it becomes:

```
[DbConfigurationType(typeof(MsSqlEFConfiguration))]
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<MyClass> MyClasses { get; set; }
}
```

Of course, I can create a factory, and use reflection to create a new class with custom attribute. However, is there a solution without reflection?

Comment: @Uno the configuration types are different, `MySqlEFConfiguration` vs `MsSqlEFConfiguration`

Comment: Pardon! My lazy eyes...

Comment: Have a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20354083/ef6-and-multiple-configurations-sql-server-and-sql-server-compact

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved the problem by inheriting from `DbConfigurationTypeAttribute`:

```
public class BaseEfConfiguration : DbConfigurationTypeAttribute
{
    public BaseEfConfiguration() : base(SqlConfiguration)
    {
    }

    public static Type SqlConfiguration
    {
        get
        {
            string databaseTypeName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DatabaseType"];
            switch (databaseTypeName)
            {
                case "MySQL":
                    return typeof(MySqlEFConfiguration);
                case "MSSQL":
                    return typeof(MsSqlEFConfiguration);
                default:
                    throw new NotImplementedException($"No such SQL configuration type {databaseTypeName}");
            }
        }
    }
}

[BaseEfConfiguration]
public class BaseDbContext : DbContext
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the attribute with the registration at runtime intercepting the configuration before it's locked:

```
DbConfiguration.Loaded += (_, a) => 
   { 
       a.ReplaceService<DbProviderServices>((s, k) => new MyProviderServices(s)); 
       a.ReplaceService<IDbConnectionFactory>((s, k) => new MyConnectionFactory(s)); 
   };
```

[Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/jj680699.aspx)