# Use SQlite and MySQL with entity framework

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, sqlite

In our application we use Database first with SQlite database.

In the program we use this method to get entities

```
public static SidelDataStoreEntities CreateEntitiesForSpecificSqliteDatabaseName(string databaseName)
    {
        var connection = new EntityConnectionStringBuilder()
        {
            Metadata = metadata,
            Provider = "System.Data.SQLite.EF6",
            ProviderConnectionString = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder() { DataSource = databaseName, }.ConnectionString,
        };
        sidelDataStoreEntities = new SidelDataStoreEntities(connection.ConnectionString);
        return sidelDataStoreEntities;
    }
```

Now we want be able to use also MySQL. It's exactly the same tables.
We use this method to get entities.

```
    public static SidelDataStoreEntities CreateEntitiesForMySqlServer()
        {
            var connection = new EntityConnectionStringBuilder()
            {
                Metadata = metadata,
                Provider = "MySql.Data.MySqlClient",
                ProviderConnectionString = new MySqlConnectionStringBuilder()
                {
                    Database = "datastore",
                    Server = Settings.Default.DataBaseServer,
                    IntegratedSecurity = false,
                    UserID = GetUserId(),
                    Password = GetPassword()
                }.ConnectionString,
            };
            sidelDataStoreEntities = new SidelDataStoreEntities(connection.ConnectionString);
            return sidelDataStoreEntities;
}
```

In App.config we have

```
<entityFramework>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.EntityFramework, Version=8.0.22.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d"/>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderServices, System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SQLite" type="System.Data.SQLite.EF6.SQLiteProviderServices, System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
```

But when we use MySQL database we've got this message when we want to use entities

> System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection' to type 'System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection'.'

The key seems to be the attribute

> [DbConfigurationType(typeof(MySqlEFConfiguration))]

If we use it with MySql, we got another error because of "sideldatastoremodelstorecontainer." added in table name

> - ```
>   InnerException  {"Table 'datastore.sideldatastoremodelstorecontainer.databasemetadata' doesn't
>   ```
>
> exist"}   System.Exception {MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException}

And this attribute generate runtime error if we use with SQlite database

So we have 2 questions

- How to use the attribute only for MySQL db?
- For MySQL db, how to suppress additional charaters in table name

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Finally the right answer at the first question is here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38327909/how-to-choose-dbconfigurationtype-programmatically

Comment: Finally the correct answer to the first question is here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38327909/how-to-choose-dbconfigurationtype-programmatically

Answer (score 0):

The answer at the first question is

```
    TypeDescriptor.AddAttributes(typeof(SidelDataStoreEntities), new DbConfigurationTypeAttribute(typeof(MySqlEFConfiguration)));
    var x = TypeDescriptor.GetAttributes(typeof(SidelDataStoreEntities));
```

But unfortunately, as we can see with GetAttributes, the new attribute is added after an already existing one. And in this case, the order of the two attributes is different. It would seem, only the first is used. We therefore recover the first error about the cast.

Finally the correct answer to the first question is here
[How to choose DbConfigurationType programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38327909/how-to-choose-dbconfigurationtype-programmatically)

Answer (score 0):

For the second question, the problem was with a different version between connector and NuGet packages