# Where to set the DbConfiguration in a WCF service for EF6 code first?

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, wcf, ef-code-first

Trying to use EF 6 code first with a WCF service, but have run into the following runtime error:

> The default DbConfiguration instance was used by the Entity Framework
>   before the 'MyConfiguration' type was discovered. An instance of
>   'MyConfiguration' must be set at application start before using
>   any Entity Framework features or must be registered in the
>   application's config file. See
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=260883 for more information.

This error is thrown when trying to instantiate the following DbContext inside a service call:

```
[DbConfigurationType(typeof(MyConfiguration))]
public partial class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public MyContext()
        : base("name=MyContext")
    {
    }
}

public class MyConfiguration : DbConfiguration
{
    public MyConfiguration()
    {
        SetExecutionStrategy(MySqlProviderInvariantName.ProviderName, () => new MySqlExecutionStrategy());
        SetDefaultConnectionFactory(new MySqlConnectionFactory());
        AddDependencyResolver(new MySqlDependencyResolver());
    }
}
```

This WCF service has other DbContexts that are used before this class is even accessed, so the error message makes perfect sense. The question is where should the configuration be set?

Comment: It should be in the configuration of WCF service, as finally that is the application, which is running, and thereby having the effective config. refer: [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj556606(v=vs.113).aspx),and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20354083/ef6-and-multiple-configurations-sql-server-and-sql-server-compact)

Comment: delete `[DbConfigurationType(typeof(MyConfiguration))]`, an try again.

Comment: Thanks, the problem appears to be caused by other EF contexts that are already created in the project. Will have to do some more research to figure out a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a constructor on MyContext as follows:

```
public MyContext(DbConnection dbConnection, bool contextOwnsConnection)
    : base(dbConnection, contextOwnsConnection)
{
}
```

Then supply a MySqlConnection manually:

```
var connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
connection.Open();
var context = new MyContext(connection, true);
```